# bootstrap carousel does not work with handelbars (prev button )

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, handlebars.js

I'm using bootstrap v3 
the process works fine without using js template , once I'm using handelbars , the previous button will crash and throw error ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined ) with index position is 0 I guess 
the problem occur while transition from the first element to the last element using previous button of course , the 'active class is lost somewhere'

could anyone help

here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="carouselWrap" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselWrap" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselWrap" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselWrap" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
                {{#if counter}}
                    <div class="item active"> 
                    {{else}}
                    <div class="item "> 
                {{/if}}
          <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td> {{product1.name}} {{decode product1.surname}}</td>
                  <td>{{price product1.lastprice}} </td>
                  <td>{{decodeproduct1.supplier}} </td>
                  <td>{{product1.nation}} </td>
                  <td>{{product1.sport}} </td>
                  <td>{{product1.divStart}} - {{product1.divEnd}} </td>
                  <td>{{{decode product1.divScenarioGood}}}</td>
                  <td><a href="{{decode product1.name}}-{{decode  product1.surname}}">link</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{product2.name}} {{decode product2.surname}}</td>
                  <td>{{price product2.lastprice}} </td>
                  <td>{{decode product2.supplier}} </td>
                  <td>{{product2.nation}} </td>
                  <td>{{product2.sport}} </td>
                  <td>{{product2.divStart}} - {{product1.divEnd}} </td>
                  <td>{{decode product2.divScenarioGood}}</td>
                  <td><a href="{{decode  product2.name}}-{{decode product2.surname}}">link</a></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>

    </div>
     {{/each}}
     </script>

    </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselWrap" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselWrap" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>


<script>

(function() {

    var Hbs = {

        init: function( config ) {
            this.url = config.url;
            this.container = config.container;
            this.template = config.template;
            this.fetch();
        },

        fetch: function() {
            var self = this;

            $.getJSON( self.url, function( data ) {
                var template = Handlebars.compile( self.template );

                Handlebars.registerHelper('toLowerCase', function(str) {
                  return str.toLowerCase();
                });

                Handlebars.registerHelper('price', function(val) {
                  return Math.round(val);
                });

                Handlebars.registerHelper('elmId', function(id) {
                  return id;
                });

                Handlebars.registerHelper('decode', function(str) {
                    try{
                        return decodeURIComponent(escape(str));
                    }catch(e){
                        // catch the error
                        console.log(e.message);
                    }
                });

                var positionCounter = 0;
                Handlebars.registerHelper('counter', function() {
                    positionCounter++;
                    if (positionCounter  == 1 )
                    return positionCounter;
                        else
                            return false;

                });

                self.container.append( template( data ) );
            });

        }



    }   


    Hbs.init({
        url : 'athletes.json',
        container: $('.carousel-inner'),
        template: $('#template').html()
    }); 

})();


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

athletes.json

```
[
  {
    "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductPair",
    "product1": {
      "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductSubset",
      "name": "Alexander",
      "surname": "Bj\u00c3\u00b6rk",
      "shortname": "A Bj\u00c3\u00b6rk",
      "sport": "Golf",
      "nation": "Sweden",
      "supplier": "V\u00c3\u00a4xj\u00c3\u00b6 GK",
      "status": "Locked",
      "lastprice": 50.497987979,
      "divStart": "2012-07-19",
      "divEnd": "2013-12-25",
      "contractType": "Travprodukt standard",
      "divScenarioGood": "Topp 10 p\u00c3\u00a5 European tour 2016\r\n",
      "divScenarioGoodRevenue": -10000,
      "smallImage": "litenNyBjork.jpg"
    },
    "product2": {
      "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductSubset",
      "name": "Felix",
      "surname": "Rosenqvist",
      "shortname": "F Rosenqvist",
      "sport": "Motor",
      "nation": "Sweden",
      "supplier": "Mercedes",
      "status": "Locked",
      "lastprice": 100,
      "divStart": "2012-12-29",
      "divEnd": "2021-02-24",
      "contractType": "Motor standard",
      "divScenarioGood": "4 s\u00c3\u00a4songer i Formel 1 fram till 2021\r\n",
      "divScenarioGoodRevenue": 12960,
      "smallImage": "FelixFarg.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductPair",
    "product1": {
      "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductSubset",
      "name": "sabri",
      "surname": "zouari",
      "shortname": "Wild Life",
      "sport": "Trotting",
      "nation": "Sweden",
      "supplier": "R Bj\u00c3\u00b6rkroth",
      "status": "Locked",
      "lastprice": 200,
      "divStart": "2014-04-16",
      "divEnd": "2016-05-14",
      "contractType": "Travprodukt standard",
      "divScenarioGood": "2.000.000 i insprugna prispengar + 5.000.000 fr\u00c3\u00a5n f\u00c3\u00b6rs\u00c3\u00a4ljning\r\n",
      "divScenarioGoodRevenue": 27900,
      "smallImage": "wildLifeProd2.jpg"
    },
    "product2": {
      "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductSubset",
      "name": "Rasmus",
      "surname": "Lindh",
      "shortname": "R Lindh",
      "sport": "Motor",
      "nation": "Sweden",
      "supplier": "Captimax",
      "status": "Locked",
      "lastprice": 100,
      "divStart": "2019-01-01",
      "divEnd": "2029-12-15",
      "contractType": "Motor Total",
      "divScenarioGood": "10 s\u00c3\u00a4songer i Formel 1 fram till 2029\r\n",
      "divScenarioGoodRevenue": 4840,
      "smallImage": "rasmusSmallSyst.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductPair",
    "product1": {
      "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductSubset",
      "name": "Andreas",
      "surname": "Siljestr\u00c3\u00b6m",
      "shortname": "A Siljestr\u00c3\u00b6m",
      "sport": "Tennis",
      "nation": "Sweden",
      "supplier": "KLTK",
      "status": "Market",
      "lastprice": 100,
      "divStart": "2013-12-01",
      "divEnd": "2016-12-01",
      "contractType": "Tennis",
      "divScenarioGood": "Topp 10 ATP dubbelranking 2016\r\n",
      "divScenarioGoodRevenue": 1050,
      "smallImage": "siljestromLiten.jpg"
    },
    "product2": {
      "@class": "com.tradeinsports.domain.product.ProductSubset",
      "name": "Gabriel",
      "surname": "Axell",
      "shortname": "G Axell",
      "sport": "Golf",
      "nation": "Sweden",
      "supplier": "Vadstena GK",
      "status": "Market",
      "lastprice": 100,
      "divStart": "2014-04-15",
      "divEnd": "2018-04-15",
      "contractType": "Travprodukt standard",
      "divScenarioGood": "Topp 10 p\u00c3\u00a5 Europatouren 2017",
      "divScenarioGoodRevenue": 1990,
      "smallImage": "litenGabbeSyst.jpg"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with Django template system but i solved rewriting the if statement like this (assuming that counter starts in 1)

```
{{#if counter = 1}}
  <div class="item active"> 
{{else}}
   <div class="item "> 
{{/if}}
```

Comment: What about {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %} ?

Comment: yeah!, it's another way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did looking for solution several hour, but it was ... little mistake - my controls was in div class="item" inside.))) Be sure that controls are outside couresel's item